# Weird coloring with @ symbol (LaTeX Minted for Python)

Tags: minted, highlighting, pygments

The @ symbol is used by NumPy (a Python module) for matrix multiplication. I got a weird coloring when writing this in a LaTeX document using Minted:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\newminted{python}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{pythoncode}
A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
BB = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
A@BB + BB@A
\end{pythoncode}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: Weird coloring with @ symbol (LaTeX Minted)]

I would like to get something like this (this is an example from Jupyter Notebook):

[image]

I am lost in the documentation, can anybody help ? A local solution (i.e. just modify by hand the coloring of the variable at the right of the @ sign) would be also totally acceptable!

Comment: pygments has  a lexer for numpy in addition to the general python  one, but it still doesn't like the `@` :(

Comment: Is there a way to tell minted to color `@foo` as black to mask the issue?

Answer (score 2):

For information, the package `piton` (which is able to format Python listings) detects `@` as an operator of Python.

The package `piton` does not use any external program but requires LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{piton}

\begin{document}

\SetPitonStyle
  { 
    Operator = \color{magenta} , 
    Number = \color{DarkGreen}
  }
\PitonOptions
  {
    identifiers = 
     {
       names = array , 
       style = \color{DarkBlue}
     }
  }

\begin{Piton}
A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
BB = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
A@BB + BB@A
\end{Piton}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]